# A remote SSH server allows only Diffie-Hellmann key exchange, how to access from Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, ssh, security, putty

My Putty client for SSH on Windows 8.1 can't connect to a remote server.

The remote Linux server accepts however only [Diffie-Hellman algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

How to install this ciphers on Windows and make available to Putty?

Comment: SSH defines MULTIPLE variants of Diffie-Hellman and _all_ SSH implementations use some of them for keyexchange, so your problem actually was that your Putty didn't implement the variant(s) accepted by your server. Putty implements its own cryptography, so the version of Windows doesn't matter and installing something 'on Windows' is irrelevant; what you need is a sufficiently recent version _of Putty_. _If_ the server wanted `diffie-hellman-group14-sha256` (as OpenSSH versions 8.0 up might if GEX is disabled or moduli missing) you need(ed) Putty version 0.73 (released 2019) or higher.

Answer (score 0):

If not using Putty, you could use the
[Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)
and use the ssh client from there.

However, since Windows 10 build 1803 April 2018, Windows now includes by default
openSSH for Windows.

The executable is found in `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`, and you can
even find in this folder the programs `scp.exe` and `sftp.exe`.

A way of making this even more functional for daily use is creating what is
called in Linux "aliases".

The first time that you attempt to SSH to a remote server, a hidden `.ssh`
directory will be created in your home directory at `C:\Users\Username\.ssh`.
You may create in this directory a file called `config`.

Here’s a theoretical example of a `config` file:

```
Host ssh-server-name
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
User xxxxxxxx
Hostname xxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: hi there @harrymc, thank you! it looks like you provide an instruction for Windows 10. How should I proceed with Windows 8.1?

Comment: I really advise upgrading to Windows 10, for so many reasons including security. Otherwise, you may try Windows Services for UNIX or Cygwin or OpenSSH or others. Some people use a Linux virtual machine for that.